# Apple Pay scam?

Tags: scam

The weirdest thing has happened to me today. I bought an iPhone XR and ran through the setup on iTunes. At one point the iPhone asked me to setup Apple Pay, which I did. I finished the setup process and the iPhone works as expected.

Suddenly, in the span of 5 minutes I received five or six SMS messages with credit card charges of around 600/700 dollars (see the image). I call the number on the SMS (0034934953999), cancel the credit card, and wait. Two minutes later I get the last message on the attached image which **clearly** suggests this is a scam. So I figure I called a scammer instead of my actual bank [CaixaBank](https://caixabank.es). However, I've searched this number and it appears it is actually the bank I was calling, so the messages are legit, but then how come the last message I received is clearly a scam?

How on earth can a legit bank and a scammer send me SMS as if they were the same account? What was the scam here? Is my setup with Apple Pay involved or is it purely coincidental?

Thanks.

PS: It's in Spanish!

[image: sms]

Comment: When you called to "cancel the credit card", did they ask for your full card number, expiration and CVC?

Comment: They didn't ask for the CVC or expiration. I later went to the bank and they confirmed that the phone I called was their official number...